# Get all Folders and Files recursively in SharePoint online with CSOM in C# and store it in one list where I can work with it

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

my current code get all the folders from a root site. After that it uses the itemId. From that itemId it gets the subfolders and files.

I don't know how I can store the Id's persistent that I can loop through the other folders and files. Then I should be stored in one list.

My code so far:

```
 var items = await GetFolderItemsRecursive(siteUrl, spListTitle, 0, tokenSP);

  
 public static async Task<List<ListItem>> GetFolderItemsRecursive(string siteUrl, string listTitle, int itemId, string tokenSP)
    {
        var folderItems = new List<ListItem>();

        using (var context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
        {
            context.ExecutingWebRequest += (s, e) =>
            {
                e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + tokenSP;
            };
            var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
            var folder = itemId == 0 ? list.RootFolder : list.GetItemById(itemId).Folder;
            context.Load(folder);
            await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View><Query></Query></View>";
            camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
            ListItemCollection collListItem = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
            context.Load(collListItem, i => i.Include(p => p.Client_Title, p => p.Id, p => p.DisplayName));
            await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
            folderItems.AddRange(collListItem);


            foreach(var item in folderItems)

            {
                var ID = item.Id;

                await GetFolderItemsRecursive(siteUrl, listTitle, ID, tokenSP);
            }



            return folderItems;
        }
    }
```

Best regards and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the files and folders in a list or library using a single CAML query. Just include the `RecursiveAll` ViewScope: `<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query></Query></View>`. You could use the static method `CreateAllItemsQuery()` on the `CamlQuery` class to produce the same result.

If you have a large list you may need to use paging to get all the folders and items. See [Paging Caml Queries in C# - Microsoft SharePoint Online](https://blog.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/dominicjarvis/2018/05/18/paging-caml-queries-in-c----microsoft-sharepoint-online) for information on how to do so.

Comment: It only gives me all Folders and Files back, but I need the exact structure of the document library e.g. Folder1 --> Folder11 Folder12 Folder2 -- > Folder21 Folder22 etc.

Comment: You can parse out the folder structure from the `FileDirRef` property value.

Comment: Should use it in the caml query or direct in the code? I'm a little stuck there. Thanks

Comment: You can get the value of the `FileDirRef` property value by modifying the fields returned in this statement: `context.Load(collListItem, i => i.Include(p => p.Client_Title, p => p.Id, p => p.DisplayName, p => p.FileDirRef));`.  `FileDirRef` is a string that contains the full path to the file. You can parse this value to extract the folder structure.

Comment: Could give me also an example how I can build the structure? I would appreciate that! Matthias